# jQuery animate on submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move the form up a few pixels with an animation and it doesn't work.

The function is being called when on submit (I have tested it with an alert()), but the animation part doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>    
<html>

<head>
    <title> Pagina </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formulario").submit(function (event) {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '-50px',
                position: 'relative'
            }, 5000, function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body,
        p {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
            font-size: 30px;
            line-height: 15px;
            letter-spacing: 0px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #contenido {
            width: 50%;
            min-width: 300px;
            margin-left: 60px;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            padding: 20px 0 0px 0;
        }

        #texto {
            padding: 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        #texto p {
            margin: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #nombre {
            font-family: 'Special Elite';
            font-size: 30px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            border: 0px;
        }

        #imagen {
            vertical-align: text-top;
            width: 50%;
            float: right;
        }

        input:focus {
            outline: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="contenido">
            <form method="POST" id="formulario">
                <div id="texto">
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" autofocus autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How's this different from your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424622/form-doesnt-move-up-on-submit)?

Comment: @j08691 animate doesn't work at all, css does.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the animation on submit event, but you never fire this event because you don't have a submit button. Add in the html:

```
<input type="submit" >
```

Comment: This isn't working http://luisalmerich.com/